# How to delete rows from sqlite table for a given date range using string value?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I pass date values to fetch those matching rows that fall between the dates (fd=from date and td=to date)and the String `txid` for deletion from table. I am unable to use the 'between' and 'and' clause here with 'where' clause.

How to use these clauses in `whereargs` correctly so that I could fetch those rows for deletion?

```
public int deleteAllExpensesTxRowForSelectPeriod(String fd,String td){
    SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String txid="E";
    String[] whereArgs={txid};
    int countdb=db.delete(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE, VivzHelper.TX_ID + " =?", whereArgs);
    return countdb;
}
```

Comment: you can not compare date as a string. you need to convert date string in Date object.

Answer (score 0):

first I think you are missing a space between = and ?.

Then, you can probably write your WHERE argument like this to use the dates.

```
String[] whereArgs={txid, fd, td};
int countdb=db.delete(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE, VivzHelper.TX_ID + " = ? AND date < ? and date > ?",     
whereArgs);
```